# Ruby object ID, dup, and mutability

Tags: ruby, clone, dup

I've come across the following concern in Ruby

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b.delete_at(1)
b => [1,3]
a => [1,3]
b.object_id => 70178446287080
a.object_id => 70178446287080
```

So I kind of have an understanding of this. `a` holds a reference to an array at the `object_id`.

`b` also has a reference to that SAME position as `b` points to `a` which refers to its `object_id`. Basically they refer to the same thing. So if I mutate something for `b`, `a` is also mutated.

What category does this behavior fall in? Is there any readings/general practices that I can memorize so I won't have any errors in the future involving this? I know that `a.dup` would provide a new object at a different location so `a.dup == b` would be `true`. Also for `a.dup.object_id == b.object_id`.

Also, is `dup` and `clone` essentially the same thing in this situation, regardless of shallow vs deep?

Answer (score 0):

Both `#dup` and `#clone` create a shallow copy of an object. However, `#clone` does two things that `#dup` doesn't:

- copy the singleton class of the copied object
- maintain the frozen status of the copied object

**Example for singleton:**

**#dup:**

```
a = Object.new

def a.foo do
  :foo 
end

p a.foo
# => :foo

b = a.dup
p b.foo
# => undefined method `foo' for #<Object:0x007f8bc395ff00> (NoMethodError)
```

**#clone:**

```
a = Object.new

def a.foo do
  :foo 
end

p a.foo
# => :foo

b = a.clone
p b.foo
# => :foo
```

**Example for frozen state:**

```
a = Object.new

a.freeze
p a.frozen?
# => true

b = a.dup
p b.frozen?
# => false

c = a.clone
p c.frozen?
# => true
```

Because of the extra steps, `#clone` is a bit slower than `#dup` (but that's probably not what will make your app too slow!).